# Ensuring Datatype of Input Parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a database column of datatype `decimal(7,4)` in SQL Server. I am creating a business layer for an application.   want to ensure that all users consuming my method should pass parameters in the correct format: `decimal(7,4)`.

What is the best way to ensure that the precision and scale will be `decimal(7,4)` when users call my **method** by passing input parameter?

Note: I am NOT looking for formatting decimal, which is mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17e87900-2c5c-4998-9697-096100dd3982/enforcing-decimal-precision).

Note: I am concerned about the method parameter; not about passing value to the database.

Answer (score 0):

do as below

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@YourParameterName", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Precision = 7;
parameter.Scale = 4;
parameter.Value = yourParameterValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: I am concerned about the method parameter; not about passing value to the database.

Answer (score -1):

You could define the parameter as `sql_variant` and then use `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` to assert that the correct parameter type was used:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Decimal74Only') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Decimal74Only;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Decimal74Only
 @p1 SQL_VARIANT
AS
BEGIN
  IF(
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@p1,'BaseType')<>'decimal'
    OR
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@p1,'Precision')<>7
    OR
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@p1,'Scale')<>4
    )
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Wrong Data Type used when calling procedure!',16,10);
    RETURN -1;
  END;  
  RAISERROR('Correct Data Type used when calling procedure!',0,0);
END;
GO
RAISERROR('Calling with INT:',0,0);
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
EXEC dbo.Decimal74Only @p1 = @i;
GO
RAISERROR('Calling with DECIMAL(7,4):',0,0);
DECLARE @d74 DECIMAL(7,4) = 1;
EXEC dbo.Decimal74Only @p1 = @d74;
GO
```